# If image url not exist on server replace url with other (multiple time) [without 404 console error]

Tags: javascript, html

I made lastposter avatar for my forum system.

What I want : when user avatar img does not exist, change file type multiple times.

For example; if `user_user1_avatar.png` does not exist, change url to `user_user1_avatar.jpg` and again if that does not exist change to `user_user1_avatar.gif` and so forth.

I try this, but still get 404 error.

```js
var imgz = document.getElementsByClassName("lpavatar_forumID")[0];

function imageExists(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image(url);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.onload = resolve;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (img.naturalWidth && img.naturalHeight) {
        img.src = ''; /* stop loading */
        clearInterval(timer);
        resolve();
      }
    }, 10);
    img.src = url;
  });
}

imageExists("bburl/uploads/avatars/avatar_avatar1.png")
  .then(()    => imgz.src = 'bburl/uploads/avatars/avatar_avatar1.png')
  .catch(()   => imgz.src = 'bburl/uploads/avatars/avatar_avatar1.jpg')
  .finally(() => imgz.src = 'bburl/uploads/avatars/avatar_avatar1.gif')

});
```

```html
<img class="lpavatar_forumID" src="/avatar/user_user1.png" />
<img class="lpavatar_forumID" src="/avatar/user_user1.png" />
<img class="lpavatar_forumID" src="/avatar/user_user1.png" />
```

Comment: Why do you care about what the console outputs? Network logs are outside of your page's control.

Comment: it's client request and i make it for three file type not more

Comment: ... and do you know why they do care about this? Now, the best would be to always make the first version available, how come it's not at the point it's a concern to your client that your fallback throws network logs?